# Programmatically Creating Sheets with bounded Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-sheets-api

Is there a programmatic way to create Google Sheets with a bounded App Script using Python?

Comment: If you are using bounded App Script, then why do you need Python? You can just create new sheet using Google App Script

Comment: I want to schedule the bounded app script to load data in the sheet. I have 100 sheets that I need to generate. @ParagJadhav

Comment: Try [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python)